# Iam not Geting login user email to insert into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

My Problem is, after user logins successfully. I can be able to get his email id but when I try to insert that into another table the error showing is

> "Undefined userEmail"
>   This is my booking.php Page

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['userEmail'];
?>

<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if (!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('login.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])):
    $email = $_SESSION['userEmail'];
    $seva = $_POST['seva_name'];
    $date = $_POST['booking_date'];
    $persons_no = $_POST['persons'];
    @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection error");
    @mysql_select_db("bhavya") or die("Database Selection error");
    $query = @mysql_query("select * from booking where userEmail='" . $userEmail . "'") or die("selection error");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) <= 150):
        $sql = "insert into booking (userEmail, seva_name, booking_date, persons) values ('$email', '$seva', '$date', '$persons_no')" or die("insertion error");
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if ($result):

            function send_mail($message, $subject)
            {
                require_once('mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
                $mail = new PHPMailer();
                $mail->IsSMTP();
                $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
                $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                $mail->Port = 465;
                $mail->AddAddress($email);
                $mail->Username = "yamahaservice7094@gmail.com";
                $mail->Password = "xxxxxx";
                $mail->SetFrom('aenugula.karthik@gmail.com', 'Krthik');
                $mail->AddReplyTo("aenugula.karthik@gmail.com", "Karthik");
                $mail->Subject = $subject;
                $mail->MsgHTML($message);
                $mail->Send();
                header("Location: index.php");
            }

        endif;
    endif;
endif;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <head>
        <title>-::Simchalam Devastanam::-</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            <!--
            body {
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-right: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                background: #f1e767; /* Old browsers */
                background-color: #FFCC00;
            }
            -->
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#date').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
                });
            });
        </script>
        <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="header">
            <h1 align="center"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" longdesc="index.html" /></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">About Devastanam</a></li>
                    <li><a href="seva.php">Seva Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['userEmail'])): ?>
                        <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                        <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-selectable"><a href="booking.php">Ticket Booking</a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['userEmail'])): endif; ?>
        <p align="right">Welcome <br /><?php echo $row['userEmail']; ?></p>
        <p align="right"><a href="logout.php"> Logout?</a></p>
        <form class="form-signin" method="post">
            <div class="arrange">
                <h3> Select Seva</h3>
                <br />
                <select id="dropdown" name="seva_name" required="required">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- Select an Seva -- </option>
                    <option value="Ashtottara Sathanamarchana">Ashtottara Sathanamarchana</option>
                    <option value="Sahasranamarchana (05.00 PM - 05.45 PM)">Sahasranamarchana (05.00 PM - 05.45 PM)</option>
                    <option value="Ammavaraki Ashtottara Sathanamarchana">Ammavaraki Ashtottara Sathanamarchana</option>
                    <option value="Kappasthabham Aalinganam">Kappasthabham Aalinganam</option>
                    <option value="Gopooja">Gopooja</option>
                    <option value="Nitya Kalyanam (09.30 AM - 10.30 AM)">Nitya Kalyanam (09.30 AM - 10.30 AM)</option>
                    <option value="Garuda Seva">Garuda Seva</option>
                    <option value="Swarnapushparchana (Every Thursday at 07.00 AM - 08.00 AM)">Swarnapushparchana (Every Thursday at 07.00 AM - 08.00 AM)</option>
                    <option value="Laksha Kunkumarchana">Laksha Kunkumarchana</option>
                    <option value="Laksha Tulasi Pooja">Laksha Tulasi Pooja</option>
                    <option value="Saswatha Laksha Kumkumarchana">Saswatha Laksha Kumkumarchana</option>
                    <option value="Saswatha Laksha Tulasi Pooja">Saswatha Laksha Tulasi Pooja</option>
                    <option value="Nityapooja, Bhogakainkaryamu">Nityapooja, Bhogakainkaryamu</option>
                    <option value="Saswatha Nitya Kalyanam">Saswatha Nitya Kalyanam</option>
                    <option value="Saswatha Garuda Seva">Saswatha Garuda Seva</option>
                    <option value="Sahasra Deepalankarana Seva (Every Saturday at 05.30 PM - 06.30 PM">Sahasra Deepalankarana Seva (Every Saturday at 05.30 PM - 06.30 PM</option>
                    <option value="Sudarsana Narasimha Yagam (Monthly once on Swathi Nakshathram day)">Sudarsana Narasimha Yagam (Monthly once on Swathi Nakshathram day)</option>
                </select>
                <br /><br />
                <h3>Select Date</h3> 
                <br />
                <input id="date" name="booking_date" type="text" size="8"  required="required"/>
                <br /><br />
                <h3>Select No. of Persons</h3>
                <br />
                <select id="dropdown1" name="persons" required="required">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- Select Number of Persons -- </option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
                <br /><br /><br /><br />
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> </td>
                        <td height="25">
                            <input type="reset" name="submit" value="Reset" />
                        </td></tr></table>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error I'am getting is 
[image]

> This is my Login Page(login.php)

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once 'class.user.php';
  $user_login = new USER();

  if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="")
  {
   $user_login->redirect('index.php');
  }
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['password']);
    if($user_login->login($email,$upass))
    {
      $user_login->redirect('index.php');
    }
  }
  ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>-::Simchalam Devastanam::-</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        <!--
         body {
             margin-left: 0px;
             margin-top: 0px;
             margin-right: 0px;
             margin-bottom: 0px;
             background: #f1e767; /* Old browsers */
             background-color: #FFCC00;
            }
            -->
           </style>
         <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
           </head>
        <body>
  <div class="header">
  <h1 align="center"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" longdesc="index.html" /></h1>
  </div>
<div class="nav">
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">About Devastanam</a></li>
    <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="seva.php">Seva Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="booking.php">Ticket Booking</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

×
**Sorry!** This Account is not Activated Go to your Inbox and Activate it. 
      
        
    
    
        
        ×
          **Wrong Details!** 
         
        
     
   
    
  Email:
                       
   
   
  Password:

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are creating variable of email as

```
 $email = $_SESSION['userEmail'];
```

and in your query you are using `$userEmail`. so please change your variable in the query as follows:

```
$query = @mysql_query("select * from booking where userEmail='" . $email. "'") or die("selection error");
```

Besides this, Please avoid to use `mysql_*` functions as they are going to be deprecated.

Comment: what is line number 22 ? Is it $_SESSION['userEmail'] or the query of mysql ?

Answer (score 1):

you have stored your email from session in the variable of $email

```
$email = $_SESSION['userEmail'];
```

you are using $userEmail

```
$query = @mysql_query("select * from booking where userEmail='" . $userEmail . "'") or die("selection error");
```

change this into

```
$query = @mysql_query("select * from booking where userEmail='" . $email . "'") or die("selection error");
```

avoid using mysql_* function, learn mysqli or PDO. mysql has been deprecated.

Comment: there are 3 scripts of PHP are these in separate files ? if yes then you forgot to start the session in third file